# s4≀s2 visually?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups, cayley-graphs, wreath-product

What does the polytope whose symmetry is (exactly, not larger isomorphisms) s4≀s2 look like? Does anyone know of a full decomposition of its construction, i.e. lattices, hasse diagrams, cayley graphs, etc?

Comment: Actually... more to the point, what is the nature of the "swap" group action offered by the S2 (or C2) group. It is said that s4≀s2 is a pair of disjoint octahedra (hexahedra (i.e. cubes), or tetrahedra) that can rotate independently or together as permutations of the wreath product.

Does this mean you can swap from any of the elements of the first polytope over to the any of the others in the second?

Comment: Ahhh... You can swap to whatever you want; S_4 wr Z_2 is the automorphism group of the complete bipartite graph on (4,4) vertices.